# path to twig template in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am working on a Symfony2 project, currently trying to render a view for my controller but annoyingly I am constantly seeing this error Message:

```
Unable to find template
```

So to my understanding there is an issue with the path part of the render function. I tried tackling this but no matter how I change my path I allways get this message.

Full path to the test.html.twig file:

```
src/Test/NewsInfrastructure/Sitemap/test.html.twig
```

This is how I implemente this path:

```
return $this->templating->renderResponse('src:Test:NewsInfrastructure:Sitemap:test.html.twig', array('sitemap' => $this->siteMap->getSiteMap()));
```

What is it that I am doing wrong...?

Comment: You should use the Bundle Name instead of the full path, or use slashes instead of colons. The colon notation only works on Bundles.

Comment: So something like this 'NewsInfrastructure/Sitemap/test.html.twig'..? If so I have already tried this and also failed

Comment: What is the Bundle name? Does this work? "TestNewsInfrastructureBundle:Sitemap:test.html"

Comment: the bundle name is NewsInfrastructure. and unfortinally this path also does not work... <faceslap>

Comment: @Tomazi try this: 'TestNewsInfrastructure:Sitemap:test.html.twig`, but you should respect symfony conventions and rename your bundle *NewsInfrastructureBundle*

Comment: How come the test folder name is written together with NewsInfrastructure...? shouldynt these two be seperated by either : or / ..?

Comment: try changing name of bundle and also add template in Resources folder

Answer (score 2):

TwigBundle ([TwigExtension](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/DependencyInjection/TwigExtension.php)) searches the templates through Bundle's folder (Resources/views) or [upper levels](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations);

I think the easiest way to render a template by calling it by namespace, like this:

```
$this->render('@Vendor/Product/view.html.twig'); // src/Vendor/MyBundle/Resources/views/Product/view.html.twig
```

`@Vendor` - without Bundle suffix, also it works bit faster..

Or

This can help you if you really want to load the template wich locates outside of Resources folder:

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(PATH_TO_DIRECTORY);
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, array('cache' => false));    
$twig_code = $twig->render('myFile.html.twig', []);

return new Response($twig_code);
```

Comment: His template is not in resources folder, also bundle name don't end with `Bundle`. so he may also need to do that and add template in `Resources/views` folder

Comment: @StrawHat He should change it then

Comment: Do i really have to have my twif files under Resources/View...? and how neccessery is it to to keep this naming convention: MYbundleBundle..?

Comment: @Tomazi read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html)